# How to fix the inaccurate mouse movement in the Eye of the Beholder for C64 under VICE?

Tags: commodore-64, emulation, gaming, commodore-128, input-devices

I'm trying to play the C64 and C128 versions of the [Eye of the Beholder](https://csdb.dk/release/index.php?id=226060) by using the [VICE](https://vice-emu.sourceforge.io/) emulator on Windows 11, but the mouse movement is too inaccurate and it constantly flutters on a moving attempt to an extent that the game is completely unplayable. I'm trying to use the Mouse 1351 connected to the control port 2. In the game, I tried both the 1351 (Acc) and 1351 (No Acc) drivers. Does someone know how to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

GTKVice works in general properly with Win11 (WinVICE does not), but please use a mouse with 1600 dpi max. Windows display optimizations should be disabled for VICE.

Comment: I found that the problem appears only when my external monitor is connected to the laptop. Unfortunately, turning off the Windows display optimizations does not change the behavior.